# Adding ajax request stops click function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've click function & ajax request in it.
Problem with the script it, as soon as I add ajax script in function, click stops working. Trigger doesn't work anymore.
Below is the code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#showall", function(e){
    $(this).removeClass('non-active-button');
    $(this).addClass('active-button');
    $('#past10').removeClass('active-button');
    $('#past10').addClass('non-active-button');
    var data= <?php echo $all; ?>;
/* As soon as I add following code, triggers stop working */    
    $.ajax{(
        type: "POST",
        data: "data="+data,
        url: "ajax_showallorders.php",
        success: function(option)
        {
            $(".single-column").empty();
            $(".single-column").html(option);
        }
    )};
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Without `$.ajax{(...)}` it works fine, it removes class & adds class perfectly fine. Any idea why this is happening? Anyone can help?
I'm using jQuery 1.11.

**EDIT**

I've already tried using `live`, `$('#showall').click(function(e){...})`

Comment: there should be some error, just view the console window for any possible error.

Comment: this `ajax{(` should be `ajax({`?

Answer (score 2):

You messed up the curly braces, it should be `({})` and not `{()}`

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "data="+data,
        url: "ajax_showallorders.php",
        success: function(option)
        {
            $(".single-column").empty();
            $(".single-column").html(option);
        }
    });
```

Browser consoles come in very handy in such cases. They usually tell you if there is something syntactically wrong.